# If $Y, X, Z$ are random variables, is it true that $E[Y|X=x] = \sum_{z} E[Y|X=x, Z=z]P(Z=z|X=x)$ by law of total expectation?

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-expectation

If $Y, X, Z$ are random variables. In particular, $Z$ is a positive discrete random variable.

Is it true that $E[Y|X=x] = \sum_{z} E[Y|X=x, Z=z]P(Z=z|X)$ by the law of total expectation/probability?

Here's my attempt:

\begin{align*}
E[Y|X=x] &= E[E[Y|X=x, Z]|X]\\
&= \sum_{z} E[Y|X=x, Z=z]P(Z=z|X=x)
\end{align*}

Comment: What is the formal definition of $P(Z=z|X)$ ?

Comment: It’s the probability that the random variable Z takes on the value z given the random variable X

Comment: Don't get this. When $A,B$ are *events* then $\mathbb P(A|B):=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}$ is a number in $[0,1]$. When $Z,X$ are *random variables* we have $\mathbb E[Z|X]$ as an $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable that has the same integral as $Z$ over all sets from $\sigma(X).$ How does $P(Z=z|X)$ fit into one or the other one ?

Comment: Does the first line in the first proof here answer my question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185849/i-want-to-show-that-e-eyx-x-z-eyx

Comment: The answer to the question you just found says $E[E[Y|X]|X,Z]=E[Y|X]$ holds in full generality. So does $E[E[Y|Z]|X,Z]=E[Y|Z]$ . These tower properties are almost trivial by the measure theoretic defintion of conditonal expectation. OP there goes the hard way and  writes $P(X=x|Z=z)$ which uses *events* that have non zero probability for *discrete* rvs. I don't see where your expression $P(X=x|Z)$ is used or defined.

Comment: I'm referring to the OP's first proof on showing that $E[Y|Z] = E[E[Y|Z, X]|Z]$. S/he wrote: $E[E[Y|X,Z]|Z] = \sum_x E[Y|X=x,Z=z]\cdot P(X=x|Z=z)$. If I change my notation from $P(Z=z|X)$ to $P(Z=z|X=x)$ would that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I am really having trouble to understand your notation. In the following I will try to give a meaning to this equation and provide a counterexample.

From the [Doob Dynkin lemma](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob-Dynkin-Lemma) we know that there exist a function $f$ such that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X,Z\big]=f(X,Z)
\end{align}
holds. It is common to write
$$
f(x,z)=\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X=x,Z=z\big]\,.
$$
It looks like by $\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X,Z=z\big]$ you mean
\begin{align}
\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X,Z=z\big]=f(X,z)\,.
\end{align}
Likewise, we also know
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X\big]=g(X)\quad\text{ where }\quad g(x)=\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X=x\big]\,.
$$

Now to the question: It looks like you are asking if
$$\tag{2}
g(x)=\sum_{z}f(x,z)\frac{\mathbb P(\{Z=z\}\cap\{X=x\})}{\mathbb P\{X=x\}}
$$
holds. (This is my only way to give your equation a well defined meaning).

***Counter Example***

Let $X$ be a discrete random variables taking values in $\{-2,-1,+1,+2\}$ with probability $1/4$ for each. Let
$$
Z:=X^2\quad\text{ and }\quad Y:=X^+:=\max(X,0)\,.
$$
($Z$ takes values in $\{1,4\}$ with probability $1/2$ for each. $Y$
takes values in $\{0,1,2\}$ with probability $1/2$ for $0$ and $1/4$ for the other two.)

Further,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y|X]=Y=X^+\,,\quad g(x)=x^+=1_{\{x=1\}}+2\cdot 1_{\{x=2\}}\,.
\end{align}
Since $\sigma(Z)\subset\sigma(X)\,,$
$$
\mathbb E\big[Y\big|X,Z\big]=E\big[Y\big|Z\big]\,,
$$
that is, $f(x,z)$ does not depend on $x\,,$ only on $z=x^2\,.$

From $\{X=x\}\subset\{Z=x^2\}$ it follows that
$$
\frac{\mathbb P(\{Z=z\}\cap\{X=x\})}{\mathbb P\{X=x\}}
=\left\{\begin{array}~ \mathbb P\{Z=z\}&\text{ for }z=x^2\,,\\0&\text{ else. }\end{array}\right.
$$
Therefore the RHS of (2) contains only two terms, one for
$z=1$ and one for $z=4\,:$
$$\tag{3}
f(1)\frac{1}{2}+f(4)\frac{1}{2}\,.
$$
In particular this does not depend on $x$ while
the RHS of (2) is
$$\tag{4}
g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}~ 1&\text{ for }x=1\,,\\2&\text{ for }x=2\,,\\0&\text{ else }\,.\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: $Z$ is a discrete r.v. Can $z = x^2$ for any $x$?

Comment: Probably not. Please review my edit.